# Integrate Vuforia, fast CV and Unity plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, face-recognition, vuforia

I really interested to develop and app with AR (Augmented Reality) using Vuforia and Unity plugin because I just want to develop once for Android and iOS, but I really want to take advantage using fast CV, which allow facial recognition for Vuforia, but I'm not very sure if it's possible to integrate, what about this recipe?:

For just one develop for iOS and Adnroid, use:
- Vuforia + fast CV + unity plugin

Has anyone tried it before? would be it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facial recognition is (already) available through a number of other SDKs. Particularly, many have been able to integrate with Unity already. Just do a simple search, you'd find:

Magnus' tech demo http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Yb_kte6e5w 
FaceTracker Plugin http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEleWOfRzSE

etc

--

Edit: also iOS natively provides facial recog and tracking that you can plugin to use with Unity

Comment: Is OpenCV Facetracker available on Unity Asset Store just like shown in this video URL? (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEleWOfRzSE)

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if it would help if this is time sensitive but metaio's sdk (also usable with unity) will be including facial recognition next year.

http://www.metaio.com/products/sdk/

Comment: The question is: does it provide for *Unity 3D*?